# PHP Simple way to replace or remove empty lines with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

```
$line-out = str_replace('\r', '', str_replace('\n', '', $line-in));
```

The above works for me but, I saw a [\n\r] example somewhere and I cannot seem to find it.

I just want to get rid any blank lines. The above is in a foreach loop.

Thanks for teaching.

Comment: you are likely looking for this one [Remove new lines from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use `-` in variable names ;)

```
$line_out = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', '', $line_in);
$line_out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $line_in);
```

Manual entries:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Your answer took care of another question and answered my first as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can be passed an array as:

```
$line_out = str_replace(array("\r","\n"), '', $line_in);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! Hopefully I will be able to figure this stuff out a little better soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is from php.net's example #2 in [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) (modified to suit the "environment"):

```
<?php
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, '', $str);
```