# Strip new lines in PHP

Tags: php

I've been working with phrases the past couple of days and the only problem I seem to be facing is stripping new lines in the html before printing it.

Anybody have any idea how to remove **every** new lines from HTML using PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove new lines from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $string)
```

Comment: no need for "\r\n" if you're stripping them as individual characters.

Comment: Would not work for me until I switched to single quotes: 
`str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), '', $string)`

Comment: +1 for showing me a better way of doing `str_replace("text1","",str_replace("text2","",str_replace("text3","",str_replace("text4","",str_replace("text5","",$string)))))` or putting it in a loop. never knew the parsed needle could be the array

Comment: @chiliNUT I was stuck with the same double quotes problem and stumbled o your comment. Do you know the reason as to why the double quotes don't work?

Comment: @sushant In answer to your question: single-quote strings are almost completely literal. '\n' is two characters: a slash followed by the letter 'n'. Double-quoted strings allow escaping of special characters like tabs and newlines. "\n" is one character, a newline. Which you want depends on what your string looks like, e.g. if it has newlines, or if it's, e.g. a JSON string which already has newlines escaped.

Answer (score 2):

the *pt2ph8* answer didn't work for me until I have changed it a little bit as follows:

```
str_replace(array("\\r", "\\n"), '', $string);
```

You can see the different results in this demo:

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/g5s8-nt3i

Comment: "\\r" is equivalent to '\r', which is different from "\r". The double quotes instruct PHP to parse \r \n \t and others as referring to special characters. The reason your example works is because your string simply contains the literal characters \ and r.

Comment: More info on this here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\R+/', ' ', $string);
```

> `\R` matches a generic newline; that is, anything considered a linebreak sequence by Unicode.
>
> https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash#Misc

`\R` can be used instead of `\r\n`.