# How to print wordpress shortcode from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a little problem printing a wordpress php shortcode from javascript.

Here's some code:

**JS**

```
    <script>
    function hashHandler(){
        this.oldHash = window.location.hash;
        this.Check;

        var that = this;
        var detect = function(){
            if(that.oldHash!=window.location.hash){
                console.debug("HASH CHANGED - new has" + window.location.hash);
                that.oldHash = window.location.hash;
                if (window.location.hash == "#summary"){
                    console.debug ("true for summary");
                    $(".HG-system-builder-contact-form-container").html('<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="5514" title="DYS summary page"]'); ?>');
                } else {
                    console.debug("false for summary")
                }
            }
        };
        this.Check = setInterval(function(){ detect() }, 100);

    }

    var hashDetection = new hashHandler();
</script>
```

This script checks if the hash in my url it's `#summary`and if it is, it should add this php shortcode.

The result of the php shortcode is a contact form generating using **contact form 7** (wordpress plugin) but unfortunately it has some errors.

Here's the results from chrome inspector:

```
    <script>
        function hashHandler(){
            this.oldHash = window.location.hash;
            this.Check;

            var that = this;
            var detect = function(){
                if(that.oldHash!=window.location.hash){
                    console.debug("HASH CHANGED - new has" + window.location.hash);
                    that.oldHash = window.location.hash;
                    if (window.location.hash == "#summary"){
                        console.debug ("true for summary");
                        $(".HG-system-builder-contact-form-container").html('<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form name="" action="/create-your-system/#wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="5514" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.2" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="ff2e2b253a" />
</div>
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
<p>Subject<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p>
<p>Your Message<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>');
                    } else {
                        console.debug("false for summary")
                    }
                }
            };
            this.Check = setInterval(function(){ detect() }, 100);

        }

        var hashDetection = new hashHandler();
    </script>
    <div class="HG-system-builder-contact-form-container"></div>


                </div>
            </div>
```

as you can see the problem is that the resulting html goes on new lines breaking the code and displaying this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
$(".HG-system-builder-contact-form-container").html('<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr"><div class="screen-reader-response"></div><form name="" action="/create-your-system/#wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="5514" /><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.2" /><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US" /><input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f5514-p986-o1" /><input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="ff2e2b253a" /></div><p>Your Name (required)<br />    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p><p>Your Email (required)<br />    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p><p>Subject<br />    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </p><p>Your Message<br />    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </p><p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p><div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>');
```

but in the html source:

```
<div class="HG-system-builder-contact-form-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because javascript cannot take strings over multiple lines as you are getting out of the shortcode.  Before you echo it out, have a look at getting rid of the new lines in the `echo` [Strip new lines in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766551/strip-new-lines-in-php)

Like this:

```
$(".HG-system-builder-contact-form-container").html('<?php echo str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="5514" title="DYS summary page"]')); ?>');
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i have the same error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @Nick This is not the same error.  Are you creating the "script" in PHP as otherwise you cannot call PHP from within browser interpreted javascript.

Comment: Actually you are right, it does work the error was my fault, but the shortcode result is not printed as html. I'll edit my question with the result obtained

Comment: How is the shortcode result printed?  As I mentioned, you cannot call shortcodes straight out of javascript unfortunately.  You will need to interpret that in PHP first.

Comment: It is in php and if you check the edit question you'll see the printed result

Comment: In which case the edit is valid javascript and I see no issues with it!?

Comment: In the html code, even if i think that the printed result is valid, it is still not added as html tho

Comment: The code on its own works http://jsfiddle.net/h9dq7vur/ are you getting a `"true for summary"` console log at all as if not then there's an issue with your logic.

Comment: Sorry, forget the last comment. It does work i mispelled one thing in the code! thanks a lot for your answer and patience!

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy workaround — use base64 encoding:

```
$b = base64_encode(do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="5514" title="DYS summary page"]'));
$(".HG-system-builder-contact-form-container").html(atob('<?php echo $b; ?>'));
```

Comment: Doesn't work, same error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <