# Why is '\n' === '\\n' true in php?

Tags: php, string, newline

I understand that:

```
'\n' // literally the backslash character followed by the character for lowercase n
"\n" // interpreted by php as the newline character
```

But for the life of me, I can't understand why `'\n' === '\\n'`. In my mind, `'\\n'` would equal three separate characters: two separate backslashes, followed by the letter n.

Why is `'\n' === '\\n'` true in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP do i need to escape backslashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415683/in-php-do-i-need-to-escape-backslashes) and [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash is still an escape character in single-quoted strings (it escapes literal single quotes).

This is illegal for instance (since the backslash escapes the closing quote):

```
$path = 'C:\';
```

So `\\` must map to a literal backslash to avoid inadvertent escaping.

Comment: +1 for supplying the only legitimate reason to use \\ in a single quoted string. (Before this answer, I actually couldn't think of one).

Answer (score 10):

From the manual ([section on single quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash

so in a single quoted string `\n` is two characters, but `\\n` is a literal backslash followed by the letter 'n' - i.e. the same two characters.

Comment: Just tried in http://codepad.org/xXixnCG9. Can honestly say that this one made me die a little bit on the inside

Comment: @joecortopasi: why? single quoted strings don't interpret anything inside them, EXCEPT backslashes so you can insert literal single quotes inside a single-quoted string.

Comment: For some reason that hadn't occurred to me. Totally legitimate reason for it :p

Answer (score 2):

It is because `'\\n'` is actually `\n` because the backslash is an escape character that acts strange in single quotes. It doesn't escape `n`, but does escape `\`