# remove line break after list items regex?

Tags: php, regex

Okay i am looking for a way to have this:

```
<li>stuff</li><br />
```

Stripped of the ending

```
<br />
```

That gets added to it when i do a nl2br function in php.

Or  do you think a better idea would be to strip all new lines inside

```
<ul>
```

tags?

This is part of a bbcode->html function for articles on my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use `str_replace`?

```
$myString = str_replace('</li><br />', '</li>', $myString);
```

This removes all `<br />` tags that follow a `</li>`.

Comment: Oh my god, it just had to be that simple didn't it hah thanks!

Comment: Normally I'd recommend going to a DOM, but it sounds like this case is pretty simple.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: Does php even have DOM manipulation functions? I thought that was more of a client-side thing.

Comment: @Cerbrus - http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php (Not that I've ever tried to use it. I'm not much of a php expert, though I've dabbled in it a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

[Remove new lines from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string)

As for removing br: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) br to empty string '' in your string