# How to filter html characters?

Tags: php, html

I have a question regarding the `filter`

I have the following:

`$htmlData` contains user input `html` string and it is like

```
$htmlData = array('<em>test</em>', 'text here','\n')

//I use htmlspecialchars function and want to filter \n out and save it to DB.

       $texts = htmlspecialchars($htmlData[$i]);

        if(!empty($texts) && $text != '\n'){
             echo $text;   //I still see '\n' here for some reason.
         }
```

I don't want to save `'\n'` to DB because it will just be blank in `DB`. Are there anyway to prevent this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where does $i in your code come from?

Comment: it's a loop var to loop through my htmlData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the
>   beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will
>   strip these characters:
>
> ```
> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab
> ```

For other solutions refer to this question: [Remove new lines from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

`$text != '\n'` will just check whether the string contains a backslash followed by the letter "n". What you want to compare it with is a newline, so you have to use `$text != "\n"` instead.

Also see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: I agree with you, but other white spaces might be there also with the `\n`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The currently accepted answer will filter out all whitespace, whereas the OP only indicated that he wanted to filter out values in his array that consisted of a newline character.