# Fixing textarea's "Enter" thing

Tags: php, html

So I have one problem, that I don't know how to fix.
Everytime I enter in textarea "Enter", it posts them not like spaces, but like "\n".
For expample, I enter "Hi! [*hit enter key*] My name is Richard.", it will come out like "Hi!\nMy name is Richard.
Code is simple:

```
$post = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['MESSAGE']));
echo $post;
```

Sooo, anyone - please help.

Comment: Look at nl2br function

Comment: I tried, but then output is:
"Hi!
\nMy name is Richard."
It puts line break, but then it also adds "\n" to text.

Comment: Have a look at this function too: htmlspecialchars_decode

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Answer (score 1):

[this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string)

you just need to replace the \n or \r to blank like this:

```
$post= trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['MESSAGE']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding the input data with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to convert it into a literal SQL string valid for MySQL. The correct way to encode a Unix line feed is `\n`. Thus you're getting the expected result.

*(You're also using the deprecated MySQL extension but I suppose you're aware of that.)*