# PHP removes line breaks when using POST

Tags: php, post, line-breaks

I have form that uses POST to send information to PHP script. PHP reads `$content` and saves it to `file.txt`, and also displays it on browser using the following code:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];

file_put_contents("file.txt", $content);
echo $content;
```

If I use line breaks in form, then `file.txt` contains them all. But when I'm echoing same `$content` to browser, there are no line breaks at all. And I mean in source code. My purpose is to use `$content` in another forms `<textarea>`, but even textarea does not show any line breaks.

How `file_put_contents` finds the line breaks?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes (with apache)

Comment: linebreak is not HRML br.  `nl2br()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove new lines from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string)

Comment: @batz: none of those regex replaces have any effect to show my line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Skye, the problem is solved. I used javascript generated `<input>` tag to send text containing line breaks. I changed it to `<textarea>` and I can catch all the line breaks now.

I can't still understand why I can have line breaks when saving to `file.txt` from `<input>`...

Answer (score 2):

Use php function `nl2br()` when displaying content to browser.

```
<?php echo nl2br($content); ?>
```

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: `echo nl2br($content)` does not have any effect. I have also tried to replace "\n" to "<br>" with str_replace, but no luck.

Comment: @darx I've tested on my end file is displaying line breaks, and browser also displaying line breaks using `nl2br()`. Can you please, show me what's in you `$content`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the line breaks are not gone. They are just not visible with Notepad or Windows based editor.

Most browsers use Unix / MacOS line break (`\n`) only, while Windows editor only recognize Windows linebreak (`\r\n`).

Instead of

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
```

Try to do

```
$content = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $_POST['content']);
```

More reference:

[Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but replacing "\n" with "\r\n" has no effect. When I open `file.txt` in any editor, it contains all the line breaks. So that's not the problem. Problem is that in web page, I can't get those line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];

file_put_contents("file.txt", $content);
echo "<pre>";
echo $content;
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Tried. No help. It just seems that POST somehow get rid of all my line breaks, but that's not the case because `file_put_contents` saves all line breaks to text file.

Comment: Is the $content coming from a textarea or input?

Comment: It's coming from javascript generated input tag. Input does not support line breaks? But how I can get them in saved file...