# In PHP code, how can I remove newlines

Tags: php, mysql, replace

In my PHP code

```
$sql = "SELECT a.SEQ, a.DPCODE, a.SUBJECT, CONCAT_WS('~',a.SDATE, a.EDATE) AS SDATE, b.content, concat(replace(c.filepath,'E:/WWW','http://myhome.com/'),c.filelocalnm) as filename";
$sql .= " FROM PJ_EXHIBIT a LEFT JOIN collection.exhibit b ON a.SEQ=b.seqno LEFT JOIN sy_file c ON a.attach_file = c.SEQ";
```

with `json_encode`, it returns:

[image: result in explorer]

I want to remove '\'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove new lines from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string)

Comment: where is the "\" that you need to be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str_replace`

```
<?php
$variable = 'http:\/\/comin.com:8990\/\/upload\/pj\/PJ_EXHIBIT\/1480308974751289.jpg';
$new = str_replace('\\', '', $variable);
echo $new;
?>
```

Or you can use `preg_replace`

```
<?php
$variable = 'http:\/\/comin.com:8990\/\/upload\/pj\/PJ_EXHIBIT\/1480308974751289.jpg';
$new = preg_replace("/\\\/", '', $variable);
echo $new;    
?>
```

**Manuals**

More informations can be found below:

- [PHP: str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
- [PHP: preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: It hepls me a lot. Thank you very much.