# Replace html tags when text inserted from Word

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE editor in textarea.
When i'm trying to save some data that has been inserted in editor from Word, it add's some extra `<p>` tags in table cells.

I have also tried replace it with PHP preg_replace function like that:

```
$str = preg_replace('/<td.*><p>(.*?)<\/p><\/td>/', '<td>$1</td>', $string);
```

But it replace only first, not all.

HTML String example:

```
<table width="652">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" width="652">
<p><strong>Test header</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="21">
<p>Nr.</p>
</td>
<td width="178">
<p><strong>Test2</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" width="21">
<p>1</p>
</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="178">
<p>Test3</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, there are many times like `<td><p>*</p></td>`

TinyMCE settings are following:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        selector: selector,
        readonly: <?= ($readonly == true)? 1 : 0 ?>,
        height: 500,
        theme: 'modern',
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
            // remove extra line breaks
            o.node.innerHTML = o.node.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/ig, " ");
        },
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
          'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
          'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
        image_advtab: true,
        statusbar: false,
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change', function () {
                editor.save();
            });
        },
        content_css: [
          '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css',
        ]
        });
```

**UPDATED**

Solution with

```
$str = preg_replace('/<td.*?>.*?<p>(.*?)<\/p>.*?<\/td>/s', '<td>$1</td>', $string);
```

Helped, but there are another problem, that after each html tag there are inserted new line. How I can replace it?

Comment: Just use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) instead of a bespoke regex?

Comment: Add `g` flag to the RegEx to replace "globally", that is multiple times...

Comment: I would leave the `<p>` tags in there, and if they bother you use CSS to change their properties. In the end you won't be able to control what users enter with TinyMCE.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto `preg_replace` is global, there is no `g` modifier in PHP.

Comment: Using a parser would be better, your current regex doesn't match your example. You don't have `<td><p>` you have `<td>\n<p>`.

Comment: Is this the result you are looking for? https://regex101.com/r/IfqI9J/1

Comment: This helped for me, but how can I disable too many new lines after each html element in string?

Comment: @AlexIL I can't see the new lines you are talking about. https://3v4l.org/OcZ68 please note that if my answer helped you, it's common to at least upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Regx is invalid, use this one instead : `<td.*>\n*<p>(.*?)<\/p>\n*<\/td>`

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the root block, see:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block

I think this setting could do it:

```
forced_root_block : false
```

but I haven't tested it. It will also apply to everything, not just the cell in a table. It's easy to test, so it won't be a problem to give it a try.

I simply dislike the usage of regexp for something like this, it's so damn ugly and fragile.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue which is multiline string with .*? And the /s setting on the regex.

```
 $str = preg_replace('/<td.*?>.*?<p>(.*?)<\/p>.*?<\/td>/s', '<td>$1</td>', $string);
```

Now it will span across multiiple lines as long as the pattern still is valid.
The `.*?` will match anything (including new lines) in a lazy matter.

https://regex101.com/r/IfqI9J/1/

Answer (score 0):

answer to the first update:

you can remove new lines with `preg_replace(/\n/, '', $string)`.

Also check out too [Remove new lines from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string). Maybe this can help you too.