# How to avoid the new line and extra space issue? Because I have contionously getting this error "unterminated string literal"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my onchange function, But i keep getting this error **SyntaxError: unterminated string literal**

```
 function OrganizationPrefill(type){
    if(type == 'org' ){
        var orgdts = "<?php echo $orgDets['state']; ?>";

        var myStr = "<?php echo $orgDets['address']; ?>";
        var newStr = myStr.replace('\n', '');

        $('#states  option[data='+orgdts+']').prop('selected','selected');
        $("#address").val(newStr);  
        $("#zip").val("<?php echo $orgDets['zip']; ?>");
        $("#city").val("<?php echo $orgDets['city']; ?>");
    }else if(type == 'orguser'){
        var myStr1 = "<?php echo $doctorDets['address']; ?>";
        var newStr1 = myStr.replace('\n', '');

        $("#address").val(myStr1);
        $("#zip").val("<?php echo $doctorDets['zip']; ?>");
        $("#city").val("<?php echo $doctorDets['city']; ?>");
        $('#states').val("<?php echo $doctorDets['state']; ?>");
    }
}
```

This is the address that I have in my database

**Al Ameen**

**CCNA street**

**uzbaskistan**

I want these 3 things in a single line, I already tried trim,str_replace but cant get the correct solution can anyone please assit me

What I need is ==>

```
Al Ameen CCNA street uzbaskistan
```

Comment: What is the output of the javascript after php has added all the values? I'd guess you've got a `"` in one of those

Comment: After My document.ready i get this above mentioned error

Comment: Yes, you've said this. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: You need to remove the new lines from the address on the server side (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string) as javascript does not allow multine strings in code (*without special syntax*). For modern browsers you could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Thank you all @Liam gabriele petrioli. I Updated my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone, Now its Working. This is my answer

```
function OrganizationPrefill(type){
        if(type == 'org' ){
            var orgdts = "<?php echo $orgDets['state']; ?>";
            <?php $orguserAddr = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $orgDets['address']); ?>

            $("#address").val("<?php echo $orguserAddr; ?>");
            $('#states  option[data='+orgdts+']').prop('selected','selected'); 
            $("#zip").val("<?php echo $orgDets['zip']; ?>");
            $("#city").val("<?php echo $orgDets['city']; ?>");
        }else if(type == 'orguser'){
            <?php $userAddr = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $doctorDets['address']); ?>

            $("#address").val('<?php echo $userAddr; ?>');
            $("#zip").val("<?php echo $doctorDets['zip']; ?>");
            $("#city").val("<?php echo $doctorDets['city']; ?>");
            $('#states').val("<?php echo $doctorDets['state']; ?>");
        }
    }
```