# How to remove \n\n characters, line break from php string

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, trim, line-breaks

I am trying to remove these \n\n characters that appear in my string when I post a form.

[image: image showing example of n\n\ problem]

My code is;

```
$text = $textdb['columnname'];
echo trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text));
```

But it doesn't work. I have tried literally every example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760816/remove-new-lines-from-string-and-replace-with-one-empty-space) and still nothing works. Am I suppose to do something prior to this? Does this work with a certain version of php? Am using 5.6 by the way. Thanks.

Comment: `nl2br()` is an option?

Comment: @nice_dev just tried it and it didn't work. I did $text = nl2br($textdb['columnname']);

Comment: First I would do a `var_dump($textdb['columnname']);` in order to see exactly what is in that db field.  I suspect that `str_replace("\n", "", $text);` will work.

Comment: @FoulFoot thanx. I did that and I got string(128) so it is a string. str_replace didn't work either :(( is there any possibility that this feature is disabled from the server?

Comment: They do not "appear" without you having put them there. How are you retrieving this data from the database? How are you storing it? Why are you using a version of PHP that's been obsolete for years?

Comment: @miken32 am not sure which question you are answering. Can you explain the significance of these questions to the problem at hand?!

Comment: `var_dump` should show the actual string that's being stored.  If you do view-source in your browser you'll see the actual string characters, including whether the newline "\n" is present, or it's some different character.  `str_replace` wouldn't be disabled on the server, no.

Comment: @FoulFoot yeah I just checked and it's there. string(128) "Oooooh shoot, Punchline!!!!\n\n\"and leaving the Lord/am like a journalist, am never giving up my source\" ‍♂️" that's what I got from the source

Comment: `\s` in your regular expression would match any whitespace character, including newlines. **But you do not have any actual newlines here.** You have the character backslash, followed by the character `n`, _in text form_. Learn to differentiate between _code_, and _data_.

Comment: `str_replace("\n", "", $text);` would try to replace an actual newline. If you want to replace the characters backslash-followed-by-n instead, then you simply need to supply a text literal containing _those_ as the first parameter. `str_replace('\n', "", $text);`

Comment: @CBroe it worked. But can you explain why it sees it as text and not a new line even though it was created as a new line? Thanks

Comment: Can’t tell you that, with the information we got so far - no one here knows what _“even though it was created as a new line”_ is actually supposed to mean. All we know right now, is what `$textdb['columnname']` contained. Could be that the data got messed up before you inserted it into the database, could be that it got messed up when you read it back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232032/discussion-between-jay-smoke-and-cbroe).

Answer (score -1):

Just use `nl2br`

Example:

```
$text = nl2br("hey\n neighbor");
```

would print

```
hey
neighbor
```

Comment: Thankx. I just tried it and it didn't work. I did $text = nl2br($textdb['columnname']);

Comment: What array? Am not sure I follow your question.